# I work "in a grocery store" or "at a grocery store"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english

I am not a native speaker but both sounds good to me. Which one should be more accurate or in fact correct.

Comment: first one seems to be correct to me. English is not my native language though

Answer (score 4):

They are almost interchangeable, but you could convey a subtle difference in meaning. If you're trying to describe your job / what you do, you'd want to say you work "at" a grocery store. Working "in" a grocery store describes the location you work at. For example, I work **in** an office, but I work **at** a company.

Comment: Generally if you work at a grocery store, that would entail working in a grocery store.

Comment: @Jon Hanna Except that in Britain and Ireland we would not normally call it a 'grocery store'. A 'store' is a place where goods are 'stored' i.e a warehouse. Places where goods are sold are called shops, though very large self-service ones are called 'supermarkets'. We do have things called 'department stores', they are very large shops that sell anything from a suite of furniture to a pair of socks.

Comment: @WS2 true, though *in* and *at* would still both be valid. Also I've noticed *store* being increasingly used of the "high street stores" other than department stores. Still, I agree that "grocery store" would make us assume you worked in another country.

Answer (score 2):

AmE here.

I would use either interchangeably in speaking without giving it a second thought.  If it were important to be precise, I would simply state my position (I'm a cashier **in a grocery store**, or I'm a cashier **at Foodmart**.)

Comment: I work at a swimming pool.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - OK. I can't top that.